# Disable items in a CheckedListBox in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Does `CheckedListBox::Enable()` to enable/disable items should behave like `GetDlgItem(checkedbox)->EnableWindow(False)`, for a simple checkedbox, I mean for the last one, the item has the aspect of a disabled item, but for checkedlistbox the item has a normal aspect but I can't select it.

So is this normal for disable items from a CheckedListBox to not have a gray aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid using `GetDlgItem`

`CCheckedListBox::Enable()` is used to enable and disabled the individual checkbox in the list based on the index you pass into it.

`EnableWindow` is intended to enable or disable the entire control. In the case of a checkbox I would expect these to be similar however the `CCheckedListBox` may handle how it manages it's check box list items differently than how an independent checkbox control would behave.

You can probably override `DrawItem` and use owner drawn style if you want to do something different than the default behavior when updating visual aspects.